# TripleDES: Encrypt (.Net) - Decrypt (CryptoJS)

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have a C# application that uses the following methods for encrypt and decrypt passwords in a database:

```
public static string Encrypt(string input, string key)
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] inputArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
    tripleDES.Clear();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}

public static string Decrypt(string input, string key)
{
    byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
    tripleDES.Clear();

    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}
```

So if I encrypt the password `testing` with the key `0123456789012345` then the result will be `+dc6bsOFg00=`.

Now I have to read these passwords from a NodeJS application (using CryptoJS), but I'm not sure how to do it, since in C# the encryption is *byte oriented* (note that in the code both `input` and `key` are converted to `byte[]`) while in CryptoJS it's more *string oriented*.

I tried using this JavaScript function with no success:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

function decrypt(input, key) {
    var inputArray = new Buffer(input, 'base64');
    var inputString = inputArray.toString();
    var resultArray = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(inputString, key, {'mode': CryptoJS.mode.ECB, 'pad': CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
    return resultArray.toString();
}

console.log(decrypt("+dc6bsOFg00=", "0123456789012345"));
```

**Update:** I know that encrypting passwords is a bad idea, and that *Triple DES* is not the best algorithm, but the C# application can't be modified (at least not for now), so I can't change how the password are encrypted, I must read them as they currently are.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: It is best not to use 3DES, instead use AES. A 3DES key is 24-bytes, the key in the question is 16-bytes. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: You're better off just using the built-in [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html) module instead of a third party module.

Comment: When you call `inputArray.toString()`, it's using UTF-8 encoding by default.  Perhaps this ought to be `inputArray.toString('binary')` instead?

Comment: No need for that, you've given your advice, no need to drill on about it. Lets keep things positive, the only outcome is a lengthy discussion in the comments going nowhere (yes, I've been there). I guess @RogerN has got it nailed by the way.

Answer (score -2):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks for the suggestion, but using `inputArray.toString('binary')` did not work.

What I finally did solve my problem is to use [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/): since I have the code of the C# methods used for encrypt and decrypt, I can use Edge.js to execute these methods from the Node application.